# VBA runtime error 438 when generating emails

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a problem where I get a runtime error 438 when trying to generate multiple emails in VBA. The first email generates fine, but additional emails when more than one cell in column F is 'yes' do not generate and the error happens. Here is the code in question below. Help appreciated, thanks

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").Columns("E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
   LCase(Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").cell.Row, "F").Value) = "yes" Then

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = cell.Value
        .Subject = "Index Option RFQ"
        .CC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").Range("cc_email").Value
        .Importance = 2

        .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & "Thanks"



        'You can add files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display  'Or use Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `For Each` syntax is wrong. It should take this form (for example)

```
Dim r as range
For each r in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    r.Value = 1
Next r
```

*Notice how we've used `r` to represent each individual cell in `A1:A10`*

---

```
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").Columns("E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "yes" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Index Option RFQ"
            .CC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").Range("cc_email").Value
            .Importance = 2

            .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(Rng) & "<br>" & "Thanks"

            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display  'Or use Send
        End With
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell
```

**Note**: as @MacroMan has pointed out below. Your error was confusing because you were *masking* previous errors with an `On Error Resume Next` statement. Using it in this way will cause more harm than good. My advice would always be to deal with each error specifically, rather than mask it.

Comment: Actually the syntax is fine - it's unnecessarily qualified which is what you've mentioned here - but it wouldn't cause an error. If it did then the first email wouldn't be generated

Comment: @MacroMan It should **always** cause an error here: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").cell.Value` since `cell` is not a property of a worksheet.

Comment: @Rory and that's why I normally stay away from the internet before I have my morning coffee!

Comment: @CallumDA Apologies, as Rory mentioned there is a syntax error in there, no doubt being masked by the `On Error Resume Next` statement which is reverted after the first loop, which is why it runs the first time and not the rest. +1

Comment: @MacroMan, phew! I was also wondering myself before you commented if the syntax would *coincidentally* work. Pleased we clarified (thanks Rory)!

Comment: @MacroMan No coffee by 10.15?? I was on my 7th cup!

Comment: @Rory we had a coffee bean famine at work. Currently using emergency supplies.